# overlapping css rule in react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader, yarnpkg, react-starter-kit

I have started learning React with the "create react app with webpack" configuration. I import css like this in react component js

```
import '../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../dist/css/main.css';
```

but when webpack compiles the css, my main.css rule is overlapping with bootstrap.css.
How do I fix this without adding '!important' in my main.css and inline styling in .js file? I also have a global css rule to set like h1,h2,h3 dll to separate files?

Comment: It's difficult to give a definite answer without knowing your entire configuration, but generally speaking, `import` does not guarantee the resolve order. You could try to import a single CSS file, in which you'll `@import` both `bootstrap.css` and `main.css`. I believe that it should solve your problem.

Comment: Agree with @OrB.  It might also be helpful if you could post your global rule, if that is the one that is in conflict.